# WPF combobox auto highlighting on first letter input

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, highlighting

Hi I have a `ComboBox` in WPF

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Select_Food" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="10"  Text="" IsEditable="True"  
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" KeyUp="Select_Food_KeyUp" IsTextSearchEnabled="false"  />
```

I am getting information from a database as options while the user types in the text box. currently everything works but the only problem is that when I type a first letter in the textbox, that letter is automatically highlighted provided any of the items in the list start with that letter. Because of this, any further typing overwrites the first letter. This is a problem. How do I stop the this initial highlight. I am trying to achieve a "google-search-like" combobox.

this is the code. help please.

```
 // While typing this function is called on every keyup stroke
    private void Select_Food_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT FOODITEM_RS FROM FOOD WHERE FOODITEM_RS LIKE @fitem", thisConnection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fitem", "%" + Select_Food.Text + "%");
            SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            thisConnection.Open();
            da.Fill(ds, "FOOD");
            Select_Food.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            Select_Food.DisplayMemberPath = ds.Tables[0].Columns["FOODITEM_RS"].ToString();

        }
        catch (SqlCeException x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
        }
        //Open dropdown menu
        Select_Food.IsDropDownOpen = true;

        thisConnection.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix this?  I'm running into the same issue - The first time I type into my combo box the first letter is highlighted and then overwritten by the second letter I type.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed it-

In my keyup event handler I added the following code-

```
    var textbox = (TextBox)cmbBox.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", cmbBox);
    if (textbox != null && _firstKey && textbox.SelectionLength > 0)
    {
        textbox.Select(textbox.SelectionLength, 0);                
        _firstKey = false;
    }
```

_firstKey is a flag I added.  This way the highlight is only cancelled once the first time this event is raised, which is where the problem is.  Subsequent highlights (most likely by the user for clearing something they typed) are allowed and left untouched.

I call Select starting at the SelectionLength so that my cursor will remain at the end of the text the user entered.  I pass is a length of 0 to clear the selection.

Answer (score 1):

As old as this is, Darlene's answer helped me.  However, I made the following edit:

Instead of:

```
textbox.Select(textbox.SelectionLength, 0);
```

I used:

```
textbox.Select(1, textbox.SelectionLength);
```

Maybe it's newer ComboBox functionality, but the entire text of the first matched item is entered into the textbox.  Therefore placing the cursor at the end of the entered text doesn't allow the user to continue typing.  This change keeps the non-user entered text highlighted and replaces additional characters as the user types.  Until they type something not in the list and then goes away.

Answer (score 0):

we fix this issue by moving the `IsDropDownOpen = true` the the `preKeyDown` event.
this is because the behavior of the combobox is selected the text whenever the DropDown opened

Answer (score 0):

Recently I stumbled with this behavior while implementing a custom combo box in WPF. None of the previous hacks/solutions worked for me. If the user types really fast, the same behavior still takes place and the first character is removed from the textbox. The solution that I applied was just overriding the event OnDropDownOpened and place the trick with the selection inside that event.

```
protected override void OnDropDownOpened(EventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = Keyboard.FocusedElement as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null && textBox.Text.Length == 1 && textBox.SelectionLength == 1)
        {
            textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
            textBox.SelectionStart = 1;
        }
    }
```